# How to change the web browser used by SSMS when you hit Ctrl+Alt+R

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2019

When I am running:

[image]

Ctrl+Alt+R will run the web browser in an SSMS tab.  However, this now produces the message:

[image]

I do have MS Edge installed but SSMS is not finding it.  What should I do to help SSMS find MS Edge and use it?

Posted bug report: [SSMS 18.10 integrated web browser lacks support for Microsoft Edge](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/7f968821-6c8e-ec11-a81b-0022484bfd94)

Note that this also affects the Technical Support menu item under the Help menu.  [image]

This option launches the integrated web browser and does not render the page properly

Comment: The problem I'm trying to overcome is that the integrated web browser doesn't work properly.  There is no underlying or secondary problem.  Obviously I can use an external browser for anything for which I could use the internal browser (and much more, naturally). @Amtwo's response is likely correct, though perhaps not authoritative.

Comment: Authoritative would be a note on the page that describes the feature that stipulates that the browser choice is fixed and cannot be changed or, even better, a bug report accepted for remediation.  Microsoft does document various limitations and I think this would fall under that category.

Comment: I greatly expanded on the answer, including additional information on when SSMS uses the embedded IE browser, and when SSMS launches your default browser, as well as workaround to launch an arbitrary application, such as Edge, from a keystroke or menu command, similar to the way the embedded IE browser works, since you cannot change the rendering engine used by the embedded browser.

Comment: I posted a link to the bug report and some more info

Answer (score 9):

### You Can't

SSMS has an integrated web browser, but it's not really much more than a novelty. It's not meant to be a full web browser.

[SSMS has an embedded Internet Explorer-based browser window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-web-browser). But it's just IE, without any possibility of changing it to use a different browser engine.

The full text of the documentation as of February 2022 is:

> SQL Server Management Studio hosts a version of Microsoft Internet Explorer. This Web browser allows you to browse URLs, and view MSDN Library help topics without leaving SQL Server Management Studio. You can access the Web browser by pointing to Web Browser on the View menu, and then clicking Show Browser.

There are no configurations or advanced options of any sort related to this embedded IE browser.

### SSMS & Web browsers

I've noticed SSMS is a little inconsistent with how it opens URLS.

- You can use CTRL+ALT+R (Or View-->Other Windows-->Web Browser) to just open the embedded IE browser directly.
- If your query window has a URL in it, and you CTRL+click on the URL, it will open that URL in your default browser.
- If you use F1 (Or Help-->View Help), it will open the SSMS documentation in your default browser
- If you use Help-->Technical Support, it will open the SQL Feedback URL in the embedded IE browser.

### If you do want to open another browser directly...

You can set up *any* external application to open from SSMS. As an example, I'll set up Edge to open from SSMS, and configure it to open my blog: am2.co. You can change the Title & am2.co to reflect your preference for labels & start pages. You can even omit the URL/address entirely, and let the browser do it's own thing.

1. From the `Tools` menu, select `External Tools...`
2. In the pop-up that opens, fill in the following fields:

   - Title: `AM2.co`
   - Command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`
   - Arguments: `am2.co --profile-directory=Default`
   - Initial Directory: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application"`
   - I also un-checked "Close on exit" so that my browser stays open even after I close SSMS.
   - Click `OK` to save & close.
3. On the `Tools` menu, you'll now see an option for `AM2.co`, and selecting it will open Edge to that site.

[image: Tools menu showing AM2.co option highlighted]

4. If you want to assign a keyboard shortcut to the external tool shortcut we just configured

   - From the `Tools` menu, select `Options`.
   - On the Options window, in the left navigation bar, select Environment-->Keyboard-->Keyboard
   - On the Keyboard Options, find `Tools.ExternalCommand1` & select it. Note that there are up to 24 configurable external tools commands, each with their own option here.
   - Place your cursor in the `Press shortcut keys` box, and type whatever keystrokes you wish to assign. I chose `Alt + Shift + F1`.
   - Click the `Assign` button to save.
   - Click the `OK` button to close the Options window.
5. Now I can hit `Alt + Shift + F1` and an Edge window will open to am2.co. Additionally, the selected keystrokes will appear as a tip in the menu, like other keystroke shortcuts.

[image: Tools menu showing AM2.co option highlighted, and ALT+SHIFT+F1 as a shortcut]

You can then repeat these steps with any web browser, any "start" URL, and any keyboard shortcut (you can even "steal" Ctrl+Alt+R from the built-in IE browser). Unfortunately, this will not replace or integrate with the built-in browser functions in any way; F1 or CTRL+click will still open in your default browser, and the embedded browser will still use IE.